# How to Extract columns of dataframe based on list of names

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe with named columns, and need to extract only those columns with a name in a list I have.

I tried

```
new_dataframe<-named_dataframe[,which(colnames(named_dataframe) %in% list_of_names)]
```

but the new dataframe just contains the list of indices.

Moreover, when I tried manually rewriting the indices as a list (i.e. `c(1,2,3)`, the code worked, but when I assigned this list to a variable and substituted that (e.g. `named_dataframe[,x]` I received the following error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(pymat, , x) : j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'x' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..x]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput`. The error suggests that you're using `data.table` but there is no mention of that in your question. Also add current and expected output.

Comment: The error message tells me that your object is a `data.table`, not simply a data frame. Did you read the referenced FAQ for data.tables? If you were just unaware that the object is a data.table a good starting point would be to read that package's documentation which will explain all the ways in which `[` behaves differently for those objects.

Comment: You can use `dplyr`  which also works with data.table
`list_of_names<- c("name_a", "name_b")`
`new_dataframe <- named_dataframe %>% select(list_of_names)`

Comment: I forgot that I was using the fread function to read in the dataframe, meaning it was a datatable. Explicitly asking for a dataframe fixed the error. Thanks